# Cannot destroy ZFS snapshot: dataset already exists

Tags: solaris, zfs

I have a server (T5220, though I doubt it matters) running Solaris 10 8/07 and I have a ZFS pool, "mysql", on internal disk.  Within it I have a filesystem "mysql/data/4.1.12", which I snapshot hourly with a script from cron.

I have one snapshot, created as one of those hourly snaps, that will not destroy.  I have renamed it out of sequence to be "mysql/data/4.1.12@wibble" so that my script will not try and fail to destroy it, but it was originally within the sequence, though I doubt that matters.  It renames successfully.  The snapshot can be successfully navigated and read from through the .zfs/snapshots directory.  It has no clones based on it.

Trying to destroy it does this:

```
(265) root@web-mysql4:/# zfs destroy mysql/data/4.1.12@wibble
cannot destroy 'mysql/data/4.1.12@wibble': dataset already exists
(266) root@web-mysql4:/#
```

which is apparently nonsensical: of course it already exists, that's the point!

Anyone seen anything like this before?  Web searches show nothing obviously similar.

I can provide patches installed if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having upgraded to more recent patch sets, I could delete this snapshot successfully.  Clearly was a bug somewhere that Sun squashed.

Answer (score 10):

This issue has now been answered, courtesy of Cindy Swearingen (cindys) here:
http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=484242&tstart=0

Summary:
If you do incremental receives, this might be CR 6860996:

A temporary clone is created for an incremental receive and in some cases, is not removed automatically.

```
1. Determine clone names:

# zdb -d <poolname> | grep %

2. Destroy identified clones:

# zfs destroy <clone-with-%-in-the-name>

It will complain that 'dataset does not exist', but you can check
again(see 1)

3. Destroy snapshot(s) that could not be destroyed previously
```

Answer (score 3):

Whilst this solution is probably unrelated to the OP's issue, I also had this same cryptic error message when trying to delete a zvol.

In my case, the zvol had been created by an interrupted zfs receive, which was sent using the "-s" resumable feature.  The resume token was preventing it from being destroyed.

To fix it, I ran `zfs receive -A <pool/zvol>`   (on FreeBSD 10.3)

Comment: Useful to know; it's certainly possible this was the case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't expect this is the issue (I think you get a different error message), but do you have any clones based on that snapshot?

Comment: No clones based on it; that's what I suspected at first, but that's not it.

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen this problem (nov 2009). Again just ONE snapshot can not be destroyed and I get the
same nonsensical message

```
# zfs destroy blue/viss02_backup/46home1f@200910211357
cannot destroy 'blue/viss02_backup/46home1f@200910211357': dataset already exists
```

And this snapshot is not the origin for and filesystem clone. In fact I have one cloned filesystem - but a recursive search shows that it is not based on the troublesome snapshot

```
# zfs get -H -o value -r origin blue | uniq
-
blue/viss02_backup/zones/puppis@200902031605
-
```

Until I rename it this snapshot will also screw up the scripts which I run to control the proliferation of snapshots.

Version information:
This is Solaris on x86 (5.10 Generic_141445-09 i86pc)
This system is currently running ZFS pool version 15.
All pools are formatted using this version.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem without any clone.

The problems occurs while the zfs version was 10. 
We try to upgrade to 15 without any changes

```
 zfs destroy -rR zpool/mailboxes
 cannot destroy 'zpool/mailboxes@bug': dataset already exists
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this long ago and wrote here: http://www.bitshop.com/Blogs/tabid/95/EntryId/101/ZFS-Destroy-dataset-does-not-exist-zdb-error-16.aspx

However this time isn't a % related issue. I'm on Illumus / Illumian 1.0, which is zpool version 26.

This is a very old server/snapshot I'm trying to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the dataset with zdb.

```
zdb -e -d tank
```

I was trying to do

```
zfs destroy -r tank/dataset
```

which shows up on `zfs list` and was getting this error.

What I found was that zdb saw

```
tank/dataset/dataset
```

which was not showing up on `zfs list`.  I was able to easily

```
zfs destroy -r tank/dataset/dataset
```

and then

```
zfs destroy -r tank/dataset
```

with no errors.

This seems like maybe a bug in `zfs list`.  FreeBSD 11.2-STABLE.

Answer (score 1):

12 years later on Solaris 11.4, none of the suggestions above worked.

What ended up working was doing a `zfs rollback -r yourPool/yourDataset`.

I was then able to send the latest incremental snapshots.